# How to receive Postman binary data in ExpressJS?

Tags: express, postman

[image]

I want to receive uploaded image in Node ExpressJS server?

I'm unable find the content in `req.body`

Any help will much be appreciated.

My server.js looks like this

```js
app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    limit: '50mb',
  }),
);
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '50mb',
    extended: true,
    parameterLimit: 50000,
  }),
);

app.use(cors());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the request body is a binary JPEG, then it isn't JSON and it isn't URL Encoded, so the body parsers you are using aren't helpful.

Use a [raw body parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserrawoptions) instead.

```
app.use(
    bodyParser.raw({ limit: '50mb', type: ['image/*'] })
);
```

Comment: Worked fine for me!

Comment: how to extract file name?

Comment: @Rajath — You aren't sending the file name.